# Translate "bigger/smaller one" into Spanish

Tags: traducción

Let's say the sentence is:

> I need a bigger one.

My attempt is:

> Necesito una más grande.

This obviously doesn't sound right to me. So, I would like to know how a native speaker would translate such sentences with an adjective (in comparative form, such as bigger, smaller, thinner, higher, etc.) with the word "one" after it.

Similarly, what if I had to say **another one** instead of **bigger one** here? Will it be ***una otra***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Necesito uno (una) más grande
```

Both are correct

```
No cabe en la bolsa, necesito una más grande
El costal está lleno, necesito uno más grande
```

Another one

```
Otro - otra
Ya no tengo pintura, necesito otro litro
Yo no tengo pintura, necesito otra lata
```

Comment: "necesito otra lata"...This is good if I wanted to say, "I need another can". But what if I don't want to explicitly mention the can and just say, "another one" instead?

Comment: Use *necesito otra*,  lata is feminine, *necesito otro (coche)* car is masculine.

Comment: If you've already said `Necesito` once already, you can get away with just saying `Otra`... or `Otro`... or even.. `uno(a) más`